# Page setup in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: reporting, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm using Pentaho Report Designer Version: 8.0.0.0-28.

When published, I want the reports to be adjusted to the whole page. 
I don't want to be obliged to scroll up and down or right and left to see the whole report.
If you ever took a look at Inventory By Line report in the Steel Wheel directory that's exactly how I want my reports to be, so that it won't be any scrolling.

I can't find this option in the page setup tab.
Any suggestions?

Comment: In report scroll will never appear. For example we are generating reports into PDF format.. when only 1 file gets generated for n number of pages.. so like wise in which ever format you generate report Pentaho report designer does not adds scroll bar, scroll bar is a specific editor functionality.

Comment: So how can I edit the scroll bar functionality?